# GraphQL Search facetOn Parameter

Tags: jss, sitecore-api, search-facet, graphql

I'm trying to use the Sitecore GraphQL search function that takes in the "facetOn" parameter. Unfortunately I'm not having much luck with the results, and I suspect it's because I'm doing something wrong and don't know where to look for the documentation. So I have a Field called "Category" and I want to facet on that when I search because I imagine it will essentially give me a count of different "Category" value occurrences. But the below is not working.

```
query {
  search(rootItem: "92B4F8E7-6324-4C01-B873-7FDC992EDDEE" facetOn:["_category"] ) {
    results {
      totalCount
      items {
        item {
          name
          _category: field(name: "Category") {
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }

    facets {

      name
      values {
        item {
          id

        }
        value
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error? or just zero facets?

Comment: I get Zero facets. I don't believe we're using any special searching that's not out of the box. Correct my if I'm wrong, but I think that may be Content Search? I've tried your solution below, facetOn ["Category"] and facetOn["_category"] both still return zero facets. Could it also be that the Category field is not text, but is rather a Grouped Droplist? @JanBluemink

Comment: Do you have item result, with Category values?

Comment: Yep, there are results for the Category values. Do you think the field of faceOn need to be indexed? @JanBluemink

Comment: For me it works with a Grouped Droplist. with version do you use?

Comment: Sitecore 9.2 @JanBluemink

Comment: Works for my on Sitecore 9.2 any changes in the Sitecore SOLR config?

Comment: There shouldn't have been any changes, just a straight out of the box installation.

Comment: Does it make a difference if we are hosting our Sitecore on Azure? @JanBluemink

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks good, I test it on Sitecore 9.1, SOLR with a Text field, that work with this adjustment.  It is now facetOn "_category" looks like because the field(name: "Category") your field is named "Category"  so use

```
search(rootItem: "92B4F8E7-6324-4C01-B873-7FDC992EDDEE" facetOn:["Category"] )
```

It is not giving a count per facet. you can do that by adding the count to the facets

```
facets {
      name
      values {
        count
        item {
          id
        }
        value
      }
}
```

Note, this is working on SOLR, for Azure Search there are some limitations, facet on an list is an issue, ARGUMENT_OUT_OF_RANGE

Below is a working example on the out of the box `Title` field from the sample item. (note item in facet is null, because result is a string not a reference)

```
query {
  search(rootItem: "/sitecore/content/home" facetOn:["Title"]  ) {
    results {
      totalCount
      items {
        item {
          name
          _TitleField: field(name: "Title") {
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }

    facets {
      name
      values {
        count
        item {
          id
        }
        value
      }

    }
  }
}
```

One thing to mention, in my returning facet name it is lowercased so Category returns as category, also a GUID returned as uppercase without dash,  if you want to search on that do first a to lowercase.